# Total Variation Distance for continuous distributions in Python(or R)

Tags: python, r, statistics, probability, probability-distribution

I would like to calculate the total variation distance(TVD) between two continuous probability distributions. I would like to point out that while there are two relevant questions(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776177/how-to-calculate-total-statistical-distance-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226904/how-to-calculate-total-variational-distance-in-python)), they are both working with discrete distributions.

For those not familiar with TVD,

> Informally, this is the largest possible difference between the
> probabilities that the two probability distributions can assign to the
> same event.

as it is described in the respective [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures). In the case of continuous distributions, TVD is equal with half the integral of the absolute difference between the two (since I cannot add math notation see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481101/definition-of-the-total-variation-distance-vp-q-frac12-int-p-qd-n) for a proof and for the notation).

So far, I wasn't able to find a tool for my job in Python. I would be interested in one if exists. Also, while I have no experience in R, I understand that is commonly used for such tasks so I would be interested in one as well (TVD calculation is the final step of my algorithm so I guess it won't be hard to read some data from a file, do the calculation and print a number even if I am completely new to R).

I would like to add that I am mainly interesting in normal distributions so a tool strictly for those is more than welcomed.

If no such tools exist, then any help adapting answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071704/integrating-a-multidimensional-integral-in-scipy) to use the builtin probability functions will be of great help as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like  the functin `TotalVarDist` from the `distrEx` package does this calculation.

Comment: @G5W I think you are talking about [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/distrEx/versions/2.8.0/topics/TotalVarDist). But if I understand correctly it is only for 1D distributions?

Comment: Yes  That is what I meant and yes,  that is 1D only.

Comment: @G5W It appears that there is a ND as well but isn't builtin(or something like that, I am not sure yet)